# Linq - list within object not saving on db.SaveChanges() call

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am having problems saving the following to a database.

I have a list of branches as part of a MessageType object. I update the list of branches in the 1st section of code then save the list of Branches to the MessageType object in section 2 and then call db.SaveChanges(). Unfortunately, the new List of branches is not persisted.

```
// section 1
 List<Branch> myBranches = new List<Branch>();
            foreach (int bid in branches)
            {
                var bran = db.Branches.Find(bid);
                if (bran != null)
                {
                    myBranches.Add(bran);
                }
            }
//section 2
            try
            {

                messagetype.SenderID = eSenderDB.MvcApplication.SenderID;
                messagetype.Branches = myBranches;
                foreach (Branch bra in messagetype.Branches)
                {
                    db.Entry(bra).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                //db.Entry(messagetype.Branches).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(messagetype).State = EntityState.Modified;

                db.SaveChanges();
```

My Create method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(MessageType messagetype, int[] branches)
        {
            List<Branch> myBranches = new List<Branch>();
            foreach (int bid in branches)
            {
                var bran = db.Branches.Find(bid);
                if (bran != null)
                {
                    myBranches.Add(bran);
                }
            }

            {
                messagetype.Branches = myBranches;
                messagetype.SenderID = eSenderDB.MvcApplication.SenderID;
                messagetype.OptIns = 0;
                db.MessageTypes.Add(messagetype);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(messagetype);
        }
```

Comment: the database structure is such that a Branch can have many MessageTypes and a MessageType can have many Branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that these two methods are a Create and Edit controller methods in MVC.

The issue here is that your MessageType object is being passed in straight from the HTTP request via the MVC Binder. So it's a ViewModel. At the same time you're using this object as an EntityModel.

This is a bit of a code smell in that the needs of the presentation layer can often diverge from the needs of the data model. Having separate objects for each would give you some benefits.

To solve this particular problem you have 2 options:

```
// Tell the database context to track the object and that the initial state is modified.
db.MessageTypes.Attach(messagetype); 
db.MessageTypes(messagetype).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Or,

```
// Separate the entity object from the view object and merge the changes.
var messageTypeEntity = db.MessageTypes.Find(messageTypeViewModel.Id);
if(messageTypeEntity == null)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The specified MessageType could not be found.");
    return View(messageTypeViewModel);
}

// Update messageTypeEntity from messageTypeViewModel
UpdateModel(messageTypeEntity);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Have a read about [System.Web.Mvc.Controller.UpdateModel(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470933%28v=vs.98%29.aspx), and there's a bit of a discussion on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087279/how-does-the-asp-net-mvc-updatemodel-method-work).

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to attach them to the context. Try the following code:

```
foreach (Branch bra in messagetype.Branches)
{
  db.Branches.Attach(bra);
  db.Entry(bra).State = EntityState.Modified;
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

On a side note, I question having the call to `SaveChanges` in your `foreach` loop. You can hold off on the save until the very end and it should still work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still not fixing the problem. Could it be my mappings? I doubt if it is my mappings because in my create method I do something similar and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I should have been more explicit in saying it was part of an edit method.